# Sort by id desc on multiple columns distinct postrges

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

```
SELECT impressions.* 
FROM impressions 
WHERE impressions.user_id = 2 
  AND impressions.action_name = 'show' 
  AND (impressions.message IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY impressionable_id, impressionable_type
```

I'd like to select from the table all last impressions that are unique on impressionable_id and impresssionable_type ordering by descending id and get the last 10

To explain this further

```
id, impressionabale_type, impressionable_id, action_name

50012, assignment, 2, show
50011, assignment, 1, show
50010, person, 1, show
50009, assignment, 1, show
50008, person, 5, show
50007, person, 4, show
50006, person, 3, show
50005, person, 1, show
50004, person, 1, show
50003, person, 2, show
50002, person, 2, show
50001, person, 1, show
50000, person, 1, show
```

Ideally I want this

```
50012, assignment, 2, show
50011, assignment, 1, show
50010, person, 1, show
50008, person, 5, show
50007, person, 4, show
50006, person, 3, show
50003, person, 2, show
```

I have tried distinct and group by but my sql knowledge is fair at best.

I get

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "impressions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Can someone shed some light please

Comment: Do you have some sample data? Maybe some desired output too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe thi will suit your needs:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT impressionable_id, impressionabale_type
    FROM impressions
    WHERE impressions.action_name = 'show'
) t1, LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM impressions
    WHERE (t1.impressionable_id,t1.impressionabale_type) = (impressionable_id,impressionabale_type)
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) t2
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This will find all unique combinations of `impressionable_id` and `impressionable_type` and for each of them will find the row with the largest `id` in a `LATERAL` subquery.

Comment: This is the response ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: @user1320651 I updated my answer, can you try again?

Comment: seems to work just testing it now, do I need a distinct action_name as its declared as action_name = show?

Comment: Yes you don't actually need it. You can remove it from both the `DISTINCT ON` and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Although you have the correct SQL its likely that I have not acutally got the correct explaination, the query does work but its selecting values that are not recent

Comment: @user1320651 How do you know which rows are more recent? Do you have a dedicated column for that?

Comment: its by the first column id

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by impressionable_id, impressionable_type
            order by id desc
        ) as rn
    from impressions 
    where
        user_id = 2 
        and action_name = 'show' 
        and message is not null
) s
where rn = 1
```

Comment: not quite the solution it didnt order by impressions id,

Comment: @user1320651 And you are unable to add an `order by id` clause?